# Analyzing SATQ scores. Please any tips help.

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

You are given a data file called Calculus_data.tab(a huge file)

We take a random sample of 30 from the data file.

The Question:

**Estimate the difference between SATQ scores for male and female students. (At this point in your statistical education, you should interpret estimate to mean that you should find an interval estimate; for example, a confidence
interval.) What conclusions can you draw from this estimation? What conclusions can you not draw, but some
people might be tempted to draw?**

**Pls dont answer the question I just want tips. Just using the question for reference.**

My professor gave me a r script that goes as such.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(tidyverse)
setwd("C:/Users/jj948/OneDrive/Desktop/R modules")

calc_data <- read.delim("Calculus_data.tab") %>%
    filter(!is.na(SATQ), !is.na(ACTMath))

calc_data_female <- filter(calc_data, Sex=="W")
calc_data_male <- filter(calc_data, Sex=="M")

n <- 30

samples_female <- calc_data_female[sample(1:nrow(calc_data_female), n), ]
samples_male <- calc_data_male[sample(1:nrow(calc_data_male), n), ]
```

If you summarize samples_female:

```
 $ Semester     : int  20169 20159 20169 20179 20169 20149 20149 20149    20159 20149 ...
 $ Calc_semester: Factor w/ 2 levels "first","second": 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Grade        : Factor w/ 15 levels "A","A-","B","B-",..: 14 6 14 6 1 5 1 13 6 5 ...
 $ Grade_grouped: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 6 3 6 3 1 2 1 5 3 2 ...
 $ Grade_GPA    : num  0 2 0 2 4 3.33 4 0 2 3.33 ...
 $ SemSchName   : Factor w/ 12 levels "ARCHITECTURE",..: 9 8 9 9 9 8 9 9 12 2 ...
 $ FirstSem     : int  20169 20159 20169 20179 20169 20139 20149 20146 20159 20149 ...
 $ Race         : Factor w/ 19 levels "American Indian or Alaska Native",..: 8 19 19 8 16 19 19 8 19 19 ...
 $ Sex          : Factor w/ 2 levels "M","W": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ParIncome    : Factor w/ 9 levels "149999","19999",..: 3 9 6 1 8 3 4 7 5 3 ...
 $ FatherEd     : Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 5 6 5 6 5 7 6 1 5 5 ...
 $ MotherEd     : Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 5 5 5 5 6 7 6 3 6 7 ...
 $ SATQ         : int  540 NA 570 NA NA 620 740 510 680 630 ...
 $ SATV         : int  580 NA 620 NA NA 570 580 610 720 610 ...
 $ ACTMath      : int  NA NA NA 27 23 27 NA NA 27 28 ...
 $ ACTEng       : int  0 0 0 35 35 24 0 0 33 26
```

**I was going to compare both predictive models for males and females but yeah I was using too much factors. Is there anyway I can use better factors for these models? What do you guys think I should be focusing on out of the factors and integers you've seen earlier? Any factors I should be omitting?**

Comment: If you are going to downvote please let me know why? Trying to work on making better questions.

Comment: I think questions about R are better answered on stackoverflow, at least that's where I find my answers when googling them... If you want an answer (either here or there), please try to reduce your question. We don't need to know your data path, we don't need to know all the properties of your females. Give a minimal example of what you want to do and the problems you face, that will strongly increase the chance that someone actually reads through it all.

Comment: Do you know a procedure to calculate a confidence interval on the difference of means?  If so, this would be a good time to apply it.